# Yahoo! email acts very strangely after changing password

Tags: yahoo-mail, yahoo

I just changed my account password. I can log into all other service of Yahoo!. But I just cannot log into the email service. I tried to access with browser it keeps asking for password though I've already logged in. I cannot use pop or imap to access it also. Anyone knows what happened? Do they stop to provide email service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tests. I finally find out the web email server need about 1-2 hours till the pwd modification propagate to it, do not ask me why, I do not know. The pop/imap pwd is changed immediately. However, the pop/imap pwd cannot be longer than 32. Do not ask me why yahoo does not match their pwd length limits cross its services ... But if you want your mail service to work properly you need to:

1. make sure your pwd length < 32 characters.
2. wait about 2 hours before you actually use the web interface to access your email.

Answer (score 0):

i think you stuck in a sign in screen loop.try these steps to solve this problem.

1. From the Sign-in page, click **Sign in as a different user.**
2. Enter your Yahoo ID and Password, then click **Sign in.**

if this doesnt worked then try above alternatives.

- login from the **[Primary login site](https://login.yahoo.com/)**
- try clearing your **browser cookies**
- try signing up again and check if yahoo has that email or phone number **exist in their database**
- **restart your browser** or try any other browser
- try login into any other yahoo email profile

Comment: thanks! but this does not work.